# Why don't I have EditText in the Form Widgets section in my eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

As you can see in the Form Widgets section, I don't have a EditText icon there. I know I could write it in the xml file manually, but I was wondering why it isn't there. Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because **EditText** is in "Text Fields" Tab on the left menu.

Answer (score 5):

Yea this one had me stumped too.

For those who still can't find it check out this image.  Edit-text is the "multi-line" Text Field option that is to the right of the "Address" option.

You can see on the right of the image under 'Outline' that its a editText so hopefully this helps someone avoid the confusion I also had.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Palette->Text Fields-> Multiline Text/ Plain Text

Answer (score 1):

Look on the left, where you have "Form Widgets" selected... try selecting "Text Fields".